# How can I insert a character code into a Linux text editor?

Tags: linux, utf-8

I need a lightweight GUI text editor on my Ubuntu Lucid system which lets me specify a Unicode code point (e.g. `U+1234`), and inserts that character to a UTF-8 text document. I know that `gedit` can't do it (not even with the *Character Map* plugin).

I'm not interested in solutions involving any kind of `emacs` or `vi`. I'm also not interested in text editors running in the terminal (such as *joe*, which has this functionality). I need the absolute simplest, smallest and fastest plain text editor for Linux which lets me type a few letters, insert a few characters by their code, type some more letters, and then save the `.txt` file as UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: For the record: In Vim you can do this by pressing Ctrl+V, the letter “u” and the 4-character hex codepoint.

Comment: For the record: in joe, if joe was started in a UTF-8 locale, a Unicode character can be inserted by pressing Escape, Apostrophe, X, hex, Enter; where hex is the code point in hex.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found a solution which works in *gedit* and in the text input boxes of many other GTK-based applications. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, type the character code in hex, then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and the character appears.

Comment: An important note here: the unicode character only appears *after* you press enter.  Until then, you see what you're typing (for example, for a non-breaking space:  you would see `u00a0` with the it all likely underlined )

Comment: @Randall: Indeed, but this is hardly surprising. What other behavior would be reasonable?

Comment: I was just in the frame of mind of the Windows-style method for inserting extended-ASCII (where there is nothing displayed at all on the screen until releasing the Alt key), so I initially thought something wasn't configured right in Ubuntu for entering Unicode.

Comment: @pts LibreOffice doesn't show the numbers. It just shows a static cursor until you hit the space bar or Enter key. Just an example of different program behaviours when using Unicode input methods.